# Is the rows affected number 0 only when no matching record is found?

Tags: sql, api, db2

I.e, if I want my API to return 404 when a user tries to PUT an object with a key that doesn't exist, can I rely on the update rows affected being 0 to return 404, or do I have to first try to retrieve the entry?

Does the db type affect this behaviour? I'm using a DB2 database.

Comment: How are you obtaining the number of rows affected?  I'm not much familiar with DB2 details, but DBs with which I am familiar provide only for determining a general count of affected rows -- which includes newly-inserted ones -- not separate counts of rows updated and modified (and deleted).

Comment: @John I'm referring to a single update statement. The update statement returns an integer value of the affected rows. E.g. UPDATE table SET colour=red WHERE id=1234. I'm expecting the number of rows affected to always be 1, but I'm not sure if when the number of rows affected is <1 if that means the entry was not found, or if it could also indicate something else that shouldn't be represented by a 404 API response

Answer (score 0):

If you execute an `UPDATE` statement containing a `WHERE` clause that doesn't match any rows, then zero rows are affected.

In particular, if you use a `WHERE` clause that specifies equality conditions for all columns of the target table's primary key, then either one row or zero will be affected, depending on whether there is any row having the specified key.

Comment: Some databases have an `INSERT OR UPDATE` statement, or something equivalent, that can insert a row instead of updating one if there aren't any matching the `WHERE` clause.  That is not the behavior of a standard `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: If the entry in the database already equals the value in the UPDATE statement, then will it return 1 or 0 for the number of rows affected? E.g. UPDATE table SET colour=red WHERE id=1234 where the colour was already red in the entry for 1234

Comment: The SQL standard apparently specifies that the number of rows affected by an `UPDATE` statement is the number matched by its `WHERE` clause (all rows if there is no explicit `WHERE` clause), regardless of whether the values set differ from the previous ones.  Many DBMSs follow the standard in that regard, but some do not.

Comment: thanks, do you have any reference to the SQL standard? It appears to work this way in db2 also, but I couldn't find any official documentation to back up the assumption.

Comment: You seem to have missed a key aspect of my previous comment: **you cannot rely on this behavior being consistent or standard-conforming among different DBMSs**.  It doesn't matter where or whether the behavior is specified by the standard.  You need to test the behavior of your particular target DBMS(s), and write your application accordingly.  Indeed, that's the case for a relatively large number of DBMS behavior details, not just this particular one.